# ORMLite throws error while querying just after an update

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, upgrade, ormlite

I’ve upgraded my ORMlite models that I added 3 new column with a default value, and the table already contained data. and upgrade is successful, but when I’m querying the table it gives an error.

> Unknown field ‘fieldname’ from the Android SQLite cursor, not
>   in:[...]

I've checked the table structure and it shows all the columns that I have newly added, what should be done to solve this issue?

Comment: how did you upgrade? Have you checked your upgrade script for errors?

Comment: I have checked the table structure after the upgrade it shows all new columns there.@stamanuel